# How to Read Performance Counters in C++

Tags: c++, performancecounter

1. Which are the classes in C++ to read performance counters.
2. How to read these counters data.

Comment: \I seem to recall this being covered in MSDN Magazine (or MSJ as it was before that). All the issues are online... and you're going to need to go back quite a while.

Answer (score 4):

[Accessing Performance Data in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384724%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

[Performance Counter Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa392738%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)