# Get system HDD usage with C++

Tags: c++, winapi, io, diskspace

I was wondering if such is possible in the unmanaged C++ code?

I'm writing a program that shows the current CPU usage on the system, but I observed that on some newer desktops when some lengthy hard drive operation is in process (say, like from a background backup process) the CPU usage stays very low (less than 10%) but the system is somewhat slow to use. So I was thinking to add to my program the current HDD usage on a system-wide scale, I'm just not sure what API to use for that.

Comment: There are performance counters covering the number of I/O requests per second, and I think there may be one for the average request queue depth.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: That would probably be it (provided I/O requests is what HDD usage implies -- I'm just not sure about the exact terminology.)

Comment: There should be such functionality since task manager shows it. Just I/O requests won't do, but if you could get access to raw (not file requests but block requests) I/O requests  that would work. What you really want to measure is data speed. And then your usage would be current_speed/max_speed.

Comment: There's already a question about reading performance counters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028337/how-to-read-performance-counters-in-c  I'm not sure why it got voted down.  Anyway, the answer looks like it provides some good pointers.  But before you start writing code, use the Performance Monitor tool provided with Windows, and see if any of those traces match what you want to measure.

Comment: @MaikuMori: Except that the throughput of a rotating disk varies wildly between random vs sequential access.  The rate of requests isn't nearly as useful as queue length.

Comment: @Ben Voigt thanks for link, although WMI would be the last thing I'd look in. From my previous experience it is VERY slow.

Comment: Just curious though, from my own search I just found DeviceIoControl API with DISK_PERFORMANCE structure. Has anyone tried it out?

Comment: @BenVoigt, true and probably varies depending where the data is located on the physical disk. You could try to figure out what Task Manager -> Resource manager (not sure about this name, not on English locale atm) measures. (Damn you were first :( )

Comment: @ahmd0: Ah, I didn't look that deep.  There's a faster way, but first check with Performance Monitor and see if there's a counter that will solve your problem.

Comment: Faster way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372652.aspx

Comment: @Ben Voigt Thanks. Although I can't seem to find any data relevant to HDD usage in PDH_COUNTER_INFO struct it returns. Am I missing something?

Comment: @ahmd0: Next you have to use `PdhAddCounter`, not exactly sure after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the "% Disk Time" performance counter. That indicates the (averaged) fraction of time that the disk is busy servicing requests. If it's close to 100%, then the CPU will probably be waiting a lot for I/O's to complete.

Another option is the "Current Disk Queue Length". That indicates how many requests are pending, which in turn is a measure of the excess operations (operations issued - operations completed). If there are zero pending operations in the queue, the CPU is not waiting for the disk; if there are tons, then the CPU has nothing to do.

Of course, if there are low-priority CPU-cound threads, then those will still run while the higher-priority threads are waiting for I/O. Windows won't waste CPU time just because the disk is busy.