# Hardware Performance Counters using C

Tags: c, performance, hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hardware performance counter APIs for Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764639/hardware-performance-counter-apis-for-windows)

I need some C sample code which  retrieves the values of hardware performance counters.I referred PAPI API's but it doesn't support windows now.My aim to retrieve the performance counters for each process running in a windows system.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is smiler question:
[How to Read Performance Counters in C++][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028337/how-to-read-performance-counters-in-c

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8764639/hardware-performance-counter-apis-for-windows